# Flutter Textfield delete widgetspan as a whole

Tags: flutter, textspan

I am trying to do mentions in my project. The server will accept a format like `@id`, for example `@15`, which means I mentioned user number 15. But in the app, the actual username will be displayed as `@Sam`,where Sam is the user with id number 15.

What I am doing is to override `buildTextSpan` function in `TextEditingController`, converting `@15` to a Widget `@Sam`  if an `@` symbol is detected.

The question is: when I am doing deleting, flutter actually deletes the chars in `TextEditingController` one by one. Is there a way to delete `@15` in `TextEditingController` as a whole with only one backspace tap?

Comment: Does your ID`@anyNumber` will always at 1st position, or it can be anywhere in text?

Comment: It's on everywhere.

Comment: I got same issue, any updates?